# Create website shortcuts programmatically with default icon

Tags: android, web, shortcut

I need to programmatically create a website shortcut on Android homescreen with the default website icone.

This feature exists with Chrome browser : Add to home screen, and now I need to implement it with code.

Answer (score 0):

Include web app manifest in your webpage. check this one [link](https://mobiforge.com/design-development/web-app-manifests-usher-new-wave-progressive-apps-to-your-homescreen)

Comment: Actually, it's about Android dev, I mean I am developping a feature that creates the shortcut on my homescreen whatever the website is. I can't add this on every single website I want to create its shortcut. I hope I was clear :)